# C# - Sockets: Port Forwarding

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, port, portforwarding

I am working at a Network Program but when I testing the code I find out that my friends (they are not in my local network) cant connect to the server. Now I found out that port forwarding could be the probleme but I dont know how I can change my code, that my friends can connect (when port forwarding the problem is than how can I implement port forwarding in my code).
Here my Classes:
Server class:

```
    static Socket listenerSocket;
    static List<ClientData> clients;
    static List<ClientName> clientNames;
    static List<ClientName> clientReady;
    private int port;

    public Server(int port)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.port = port;
    }
    private void Server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        consoleList.Items.Add("Starting Server on " + Packet.GetIP4Address() + ":" + port);

        listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clients = new List<ClientData>();
        clientNames = new List<ClientName>();
        clientReady = new List<ClientName>();

        IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Packet.GetIP4Address()), port);
        try
        {
            listenerSocket.Bind(point);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Port ist schon benutzt!");
            Close();
        }

        Thread listenThread = new Thread(ListenThread);
        listenThread.Start();
    }

    static void ListenThread()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            listenerSocket.Listen(0);
            ClientData data = new ClientData(listenerSocket.Accept());
            clients.Add(data);
        }
    }

    public static void ResetReadyClientList()
    {
        ResetReadyClientList_Server();
    }

    private static void ResetReadyClientList_Server()
    {
        clientReady.Clear();
    }

    public static List<ClientName> GetReadyClientList()
    {
        return clientReady;
    }

    public static List<ClientName> GetClientList()
    {
        return clientNames;
    }

    public static void Data_IN(object cSocket)
    {
        Socket clientScoket = (Socket)cSocket;

        byte[] buffer;
        int readBytes;

        for (;;)
        {
            buffer = new byte[clientScoket.SendBufferSize];

            readBytes = clientScoket.Receive(buffer);

            if(readBytes > 0)
            {
                Packet packet = new Packet(buffer);
                DataManager(packet);
            }
        }
    }

    static List<String> packetsReceived = new List<string>();
    static List<String> clientsHasDownloaded = new List<string>();

    static String path;

    public static void DataManager(Packet p)
    {
        switch (p.packetType)
        {
            case PacketType.OutWindow:
                String name = GetName(p.senderID);
                MessageBox.Show(name + " hat aus dem Fenster geklickt!");
                break;
            case PacketType.RegisterName:
                ClientName cName = new ClientName(p.senderID, p.gData[0]);

                clientNames.Add(cName);
                break;
            case PacketType.Answer:
                String senderName = GetName(p.senderID);
                String answer = p.gData[0];
                MessageBox.Show("Spieler " + senderName + " hat " + answer + " getippt!");
                ClientName c = new ClientName(p.senderID, GetName(p.senderID));
                if (clientReady.Contains(c)) clientReady.Remove(c);
                clientReady.Add(c);
                break;
            case PacketType.HasDownloaded:
                clientsHasDownloaded.Add(p.senderID);
                if (clientsHasDownloaded.Count == clients.Count)
                {
                    SoundHostForm form = new SoundHostForm();
                    form.ShowDialog();
                    path = p.gData[0];
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    static ClientData GetClientData(String id)
    {
        foreach (ClientData c in clients)
        {
            if(c.id == id)
            {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void SendFileToAll(String path)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => SendFile(path));
        t.Start();
    }

    private static void SendFile(String path)
    {
        clientsHasDownloaded.Clear();

        Uri downloadLink = FileTransfer.UploadFile(path);

        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.CanDownload, "server");
        p.gData.Add(downloadLink.ToString());

        foreach (ClientData data in clients)
        {
            data.clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
        }
    }

    public static void SendPacketToAll(Packet p)
    {
        foreach(ClientData data in clients)
        {
            data.clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
        }
    }

    static String GetName(String id)
    {
        foreach (ClientName c in clientNames)
        {
            if (c.id == id)
            {
                return c.name;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
class ClientData
{
    public Socket clientSocket;
    public Thread clientThread;
    public String id;

    public ClientData()
    {
        id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        clientThread = new Thread(Server.Data_IN);
        clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
        SendRegisterationPacket();
    }

    public ClientData(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        clientThread = new Thread(Server.Data_IN);
        clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
        SendRegisterationPacket();
    }

    public void SendRegisterationPacket()
    {
        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Registration, "server");
        p.gData.Add(id);
        clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
    }
}

public class ClientName
{
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public ClientName(String id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static Socket master;
    public string username;
    public static string id;
    private String ip;
    private int port;

    public Client(String username, String ipPortString)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.username = username;
        ip = ipPortString.Split(':')[0];
        port = Convert.ToInt32(ipPortString.Split(':')[1]);
    }
    private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    public void Start()
    {
        master = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        try
        {
            master.Connect(point);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Verbinden! Code: 0x156f237" + "\n" + "Der Server konnte nicht gefunden werden!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Start();
        }
        Thread t = new Thread(Data_IN);
        t.Start();
    }

    void Data_IN()
    {
            byte[] buffer;
            int readBytes;

            for (;;)
            {
                buffer = new byte[master.SendBufferSize];
                readBytes = master.Receive(buffer);

                if (readBytes > 0)
                {
                    DataManager(new Packet(buffer));
                }
            }
    }

    static List<String> packetsReceived = new List<string>();
    static TippForm tippFormCache;

    void DataManager(Packet p)
    {
        PacketType type = p.packetType;
        switch (type)
        {
            case PacketType.Registration:
                id = p.gData[0];
                Packet rp = new Packet(PacketType.RegisterName, id);
                rp.gData.Add(username);
                master.Send(rp.ToBytes());
                break;
            case PacketType.Window:
                String windowID = p.gData[0];
                if (windowID == ABCDForm.SERIALAZIE_ID)
                {
                    if (p.senderID == "server")
                    {
                        if (!packetsReceived.Contains(p.packetID))
                        {
                            ABCDForm form = new ABCDForm(id, p.gData[1], p.gData[2], p.gData[3], p.gData[4], p.gData[5]);
                            if (!IsOpened(form))
                            {
                                form.ShowDialog();
                                packetsReceived.Add(p.packetID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (windowID == OpenAnswerForm.SERIALIZE_ID)
                {
                    if (p.senderID == "server")
                    {
                        if (!packetsReceived.Contains(p.packetID))
                        {
                            OpenAnswerForm form = new OpenAnswerForm(id, p.gData[1]);
                            if (!IsOpened(form))
                            {
                                form.ShowDialog();
                                packetsReceived.Add(p.packetID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (windowID == TippForm.SERIALIZE_ID)
                {
                    if (p.senderID == "server")
                    {
                        if (!packetsReceived.Contains(p.packetID))
                        {
                            tippFormCache = new TippForm(id, p.gData[1], p.gData[2], p.gData[3], p.gData[4], p.gData[5]);
                            if (!IsOpened(tippFormCache))
                            {
                                tippFormCache.ShowDialog();
                                packetsReceived.Add(p.packetID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (windowID == SoundForm.SERIALAZIE_ID)
                {
                    if (p.senderID == "server")
                    {
                        if (!packetsReceived.Contains(p.packetID))
                        {
                            SoundForm form = new SoundForm(id, p.gData[1]);
                            if (!IsOpened(form))
                            {
                                form.ShowDialog();
                                packetsReceived.Add(p.packetID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (windowID == VideoPlayerForm.SERIALIZE_ID)
                {
                    if (p.senderID == "server")
                    {
                        if (!packetsReceived.Contains(p.packetID))
                        {
                            playerForm = new VideoPlayerForm(id);
                            if (!IsOpened(playerForm))
                            {
                                Thread t = new Thread(() => OpenVideoPlayerWithSTA(p));
                                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                                t.Start();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case PacketType.OpenNewTipp:
                if(tippFormCache != null)
                {
                    tippFormCache.OpenNewTipp();
                }
                break;
            case PacketType.CanDownload:
                if(p.senderID == "server")
                {
                    Uri downloadLink = new Uri(p.gData[0]);

                    String uri = FileTransfer.DownloadFile(downloadLink);

                    Packet replyPacket = new Packet(PacketType.HasDownloaded, id);
                    replyPacket.gData.Add(uri);
                    master.Send(replyPacket.ToBytes());
                }
                break;
            case PacketType.Play:
                if (IsOpened(playerForm))
                {
                    playerForm.Start();
                }
                break;
            case PacketType.TogglePause:
                if (IsOpened(playerForm))
                {
                    playerForm.Pause();
                }
                break;
            case PacketType.Stop:
                if (IsOpened(playerForm))
                {
                    playerForm.Stop();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void OpenVideoPlayerWithSTA(Packet p)
    {
        playerForm.ShowDialog();
        packetsReceived.Add(p.packetID);
    }

    private static VideoPlayerForm playerForm;

    private static bool IsOpened(Form form)
    {
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach(Form f in fc)
        {
            if(f == form)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And my Packet Class / Server Data:

```
[Serializable]
public class Packet
{
    public List<String> gData;
    public int packetInt;
    public bool packetBool;
    public string senderID;
    public PacketType packetType;
    public string packetID;

    public Packet(PacketType packetType, string senderID)
    {
        gData = new List<String>();
        this.senderID = senderID;
        this.packetType = packetType;
        packetID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public Packet(byte[] bytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        ms.Position = 0;

        Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        ms.Close();

        gData = p.gData;
        packetBool = p.packetBool;
        packetInt = p.packetInt;
        packetType = p.packetType;
        senderID = p.senderID;
        packetID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        ms.Position = 0;

        bf.Serialize(ms, this);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string GetIP4Address()
    {
        IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        foreach(IPAddress ip in ips)
        {
            if(ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "127.0.0.1";
    }
}

public enum PacketType
{
    Registration,
    Window,
 /*[0] = FormID
 *
 * ABCD:
 * [1] = Frage
 * [2] = A
 * [3] = B
 * [4] = C
 * [5] = D
 * 
 * OPEN:
 * [1] = Frage
 * 
 * TIPP:
 * [1] = 1. Tipp
 * [2] = 2. Tipp
 * [3] = 3. Tipp
 * [4] = 4. Tipp
 * [5] = 5. Tipp
 * 
 * SOUND:
 * [1] = Uri
 */
    Answer,//[0] = Antwort
    OutWindow,
    RegisterName,
    Play,
    TogglePause,
    Stop,
    OpenNewTipp,
    CanDownload,
    HasDownloaded
}
```

I hope you can help me guys.

Comment: Port forwarding is done on your NAT device, usually your router or firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You activate port forwarding in the router/NAT that connects you to the Internet. Then your friends'clients should have your public IP address (the one of the router to the Internet Provider, you can see this address logging into the router/NAT) and should send the messages to a specific port. You go to the router and configure port forwarding. This assuming local network means your network is behind a router that connects you to the Internet.

Comment: When I enabled the port forwarding in my router can my friends connect then?

Comment: I opened the ports but the ports are only open on the external IP

Comment: @RageSkilln yes the port is open on the external IP. Your friends from outside the local network will send messages to the external IP to that port. When you enable port forwarding you indicate that messages to that port will be sent to your real server with the local IP address, to the specified port.